# Getting the lowest record for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm having a problem with selecting data from my table, where in I'm trying to select a group of records that have some fields with duplicate values, I want to select the ones with the lowest value, however since I'm fairly new to SQL, I'm at a dead end right now on what syntax should I use to get only the lowest values.

```
Example

SEQ_NO     ID_NO     
01          1990
02          1990
03          1991
05          1890
08          1890
01          1992
```

I only want to select all the records with  low SEQ_NO, so I should get all of the records from 1990 to 1992, but only each ID_NO has only the lowest SEQ_NO.

What syntax should I use to remove the unnecessary records (for example, remove the SEQ_NO for 1990)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar you should just posted the answer instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `MIN`, which is an *AGGREGATE FUNCTION* and a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT  ID_NO, MIN(SEQ_NO) LowestVALUE
FROM    Table1
WHERE   ID_NO BETWEEN 1990 AND 1992
GROUP   BY ID_NO
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1bd93/10)